# How to set logging level names?

Tags: python, logging, syslog, rsyslog

In order to improve readability I want to change level names for my logging system. My current approach is to use `logging.addLevelName()`. Also I want the logger write to `stderr` and syslog. I can achieve both with the following code:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.addLevelName(logging.CRITICAL, "(CC)")
logging.addLevelName(logging.ERROR, "(EE)")
logging.addLevelName(logging.WARNING, "(WW)")
logging.addLevelName(logging.INFO, "(II)")
logging.addLevelName(logging.DEBUG, "(DD)")
logging.addLevelName(logging.NOTSET, "(--)")

logger = logging.getLogger('mylogger')
logger.addHandler(logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address="/dev/log"))
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
    '[%(asctime)s %(levelname)s] %(message)s', datefmt="%y%m%d-%H%M%S"))
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.propagate = False

logger.debug("debug")
logger.info("info")
logger.warning("warning")
logger.error("error")
logger.critical("critical")
```

The output on the terminal now looks like this:

```
[180303-224014 (DD)] debug
[180303-224014 (II)] info
[180303-224014 (WW)] warning
[180303-224014 (EE)] error
[180303-224014 (CC)] critical
```

But unfortunately the syslog-handler now writes all messages to the `WARNING` level:

```
Mar  3 22:40:14 user.warning debug 
Mar  3 22:40:14 user.warning info 
Mar  3 22:40:14 user.warning warning 
Mar  3 22:40:14 user.warning error 
Mar  3 22:40:14 user.warning critical
```

Is this a bug in Pythons `logging` module? Is there a better way to just set the strings used for `'%(levelname)s'`?

Answer (score 2):

It might qualify as a bug. The `SysLogHandler` uses `self.priority_map.get(levelName, "warning")` to determine the priority to send to `syslog`, and it appears `addLevelName` doesn't (or possibly cannot) update the map. As a workaround, you could update it manually:

```
SysLogHandler.priority_names.update({
  '(CC)': logging.LOG_CRIT,
  '(EE)': logging.LOG_ERR,
  # etc
})
```

Comment: If you fix it, feel free to provide a working self-answer, and I'll delete this.